# Permanently remove Pivotal tc from STS

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using STS since a long time and the only feature annoys me is, it creates a new **Pivotal tc Server** instance in every workspace created and I never use Pivotal tc.

**Can anyone tell me how to completely remove *Pivotal tc Server* from STS installation?**

I have tried to update the artifacts.xml file, bundles.info (equinox) and bluntly deleting the features for Pivotal tc but I've never got clean result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you unzipped the distribution it should have a folder with tc-server in it. Simply delete that entire folder and STS will no longer try and create a tc-server install in your workspace.

For example in my installation it looks like this:

`$ ls -la sts-bundle/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 kdvolder kdvolder 4096 Oct 12 05:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 kdvolder kdvolder 4096 Nov  6 14:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 kdvolder kdvolder 4096 Oct 11 04:03 legal
drwxr-xr-x 11 kdvolder kdvolder 4096 Oct 13 07:56 pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.8.RELEASE
drwxr-xr-x  9 kdvolder kdvolder 4096 Nov  3 15:41 sts-3.9.1.RELEASE`

So simply delete the folder `pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.8.RELEASE`.